# Gradle build error: Could not read file for compileReleaseKotlin/caches-jvm/lookups

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, caching

I have a react native app, which uses a library which also has some native (Android) code.

I got a random Gradle error in my github action which builds the app.

Here is the error message:

```
Could not read path '/home/runner/work/my-rn-app/my-rn-app/node_modules/@org/mobile-native-utils/android/build/kotlin/compileReleaseKotlin/caches-jvm/lookups'.
```